# How can I enable or disable the eclipse new wizard depending on the project?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

My Eclipse product has several project types.

And I extend "org.eclipse.ui.newWizards" for adding a specific file.

But the file is necessary only one of the project types.

So.. How can I enable or disable the eclipse new wizard depending on the project?

Your replay will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't a way. Because there is no notion of "current project" at Workbench level in Eclipse.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to disable / not show a wizard under eclipse : File -> New -> WizardName .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119904/hi-is-it-possible-to-disable-not-show-a-wizard-under-eclipse   :   is it possible to make a wizard disabled under New -> Select a wizard

Answer (score 1):

Use the [commonWizard declaration](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_navigator_navigatorContent.html&anchor=e.commonWizard) of the navigatorContent extension point. CDT uses this to hide the "New C file" wizards as long as you have not yet created a C project, so you basically clone the declaration from org.eclipse.cdt.ui for your case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63919833/how-to-disable-not-show-a-wizard-in-eclipse   How can I make enablement work when a String value equal to a key.