# Hi, is it possible to disable / not show a wizard under eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

is it possible to disable / not show a wizard under eclipse

For example : File -> New -> WizardName
Same way :    File -> New -> Other -> Select a wizard -> Wizard Category Name -> WizardName

I can make the wizard not shown in Project Explorer view via propertyTesters.

But I want to disable a wizard under File -> New -> WizardName ...

How can we do this ?

Comment: I want to make it visible via a variable that can change via a string key value like isWizardEnabled();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think you could hide your wizard using the Activities Framework. The `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point allows you to define a set of UI contributions that can be collectively shown or hidden. An extension can also be created for a single UI contribution, like your wizard.

You simply define an `activity` element using the extension, giving it an `id` and a `name`. You can also attach an `enabledWhen` element to the activity, allowing you to control its visibility using any core expression, including the `test` element which allows you to incorporate a property tester.

```
<activity
    id="your.plugin.id.activities.controlwizardvisiblity"
    name="Control My Wizard Visibility">
    <enabledWhen>
        <test
              property="your.property.tester.info">
        </test>
     </enabledWhen>
</activity>
```

Once your activity is defined, you can attach UI contributions to it using an `activityPatternBinding` element. The binding references the activity id created above and then specifies a `pattern` attribute in the format of:

```
your.plugin.id/your.contribution.id
```

The `pattern` can be a regular expression matching many UI contributions, or if you set the `isEqualityPattern="false"` the `pattern` can directly specify a single plugin id/contribution id combination. In your case, that's probably what you want to do, and it would look something like this.

```
<activityPatternBinding
    activityId="your.plugin.id.activities.controlwizardvisiblity"
    isEqualityPattern="false"
    pattern="your.plugin.id/your.wizard.id">
</activityPatternBinding>
```

Comment: http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/ this link with your post solved the issue.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_activities_get_enabled%3F this link is also useful.

Comment: after getting activity manager as described in vogella'Ds link : IActivityManager activityManager = activitySupport.getActivityManager();
instead of generating an empty Set enabledActivities = new HashSet(); use activityManager.getEnabledActivityIds() method to get the list of activity set and add / remove id = "de.vogella.rcp.activities.view";
 

activitySupport.setEnabledActivityIds(enabledActivities);

Comment: If you generate and add to a new set than other enabled activities will disapear like terminal and other some cdt activities. Please check vogella's block about eclipse activities. The link is in the first comment. And use the comment above to add and remove to existing activities.